# How to combine monitors in Terraform which are dynamically generated?

Tags: terraform, datadog

Two monitors get created `(MonitorA(service1) , MonitorA(service2))` from an iteration. Example:

services= ["service1", "service2"]

```
resource "datadog_monitor" "MonitorA" {
  count    = contains(local.services, var.app_key) ? 1 : 0
```

}

Two more monitors are created `(MonitorB(service1) , MonitorB(service2))`:

```
resource "datadog_monitor" "MonitorB" {
count    = contains(local.services, var.app_key) ? 1 : 0
```

}

`count` here is, if the condition is true, it is created once for each value in services list.

Now, I want to create a composite monitor which should combine the monitors  `MonitorA` || `MonitorB`.

Obviously, I can't write the query as `${datadog_monitor.MonitorA.id} || ${datadog_monitor.MonitorB.id}` as there are 2 monitors created `(MonitorA(service1) , MonitorA(service2))` for each MOnitorA

I also can't write it like this: `${datadog_monitor.MonitorA[count.index].id} || ${datadog_monitor.MonitorB[count.index].id}`

So, how do I get the result like below?

Iteration 1: MyCompositeMonitor which should create a monitor in the first iteration taking `MonitorA(service1) && MonitorB(service1)`

Iteration 2:

```
(MonitorA(service2) &&  MonitorB(service2)) 
and so on
```

unfortunately `${datadog_monitor.MonitorA[count.index]` doesn't work because it creates 2 monitors and there would be 2 ids. Anyone has any idea on how to approach this complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're describing the operation that's known formally as [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), which takes two or more sets of values and returns a set of tuples containing all of the possible pairs across all of the sets.

Terraform offers that operation as [the built-in `setproduct` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/setproduct). Terraform's function also extends the idea to support *lists* as input, in which case it produces a list of tuples. Your resources that use `count` are each represented in the Terraform language as a list, and so you can produce the data structure you want by passing both resources to this function:

```
setproduct(datadog_monitor.MonitorA, datadog_monitor.MonitorB)
```

Using the notation you used in your question, that would produce the following pairs:

- `MonitorA(service1), MonitorB(service1)`
- `MonitorA(service1), MonitorB(service2)`
- `MonitorA(service2), MonitorB(service1)`
- `MonitorA(service2), MonitorB(service2)`

---

Some parts of what you've said make me question whether I've made the right assumption that you want a cartesian product: you might instead just want to correlate across both while matching by index, which would give only two items instead of the four I listed above:

- `MonitorA(service1), MonitorB(service1)`
- `MonitorA(service2), MonitorB(service2)`

If that's true then there isn't a built-in function for *that* operation, but you can describe the transformation directly using a [`for` expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for):

```
[
  for i, monitor_a in datadog_monitor.MonitorA :
  [monitor_a, datadog_monitor.MonitorB[i]]
]
```

This uses the element indices from `datadog_monitor.MonitorA` to look up the corresponding elements of `datadog_monitor.MonitorB`. This will work only if both resources have the same `count` value, because it relies on there being a one-to-one correspondance between the elements of each list.

Comment: Thank you so much  @Martin. Sorry I wasn't clear in my question. I do not want a cartesian product. I'll modify my question.

Comment: Does the second part of my answer match what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, partly. Unfortunately not completely. But thank you so much for your time. We have decided to do this functionality later xD